# read-file-name: input an non-existing file with a default name in ido

Tags: files, ido, filenames

I'd like to ask to the user where to save a `.png` file, where I provide some defaults, like:

```
(read-file-name  "Picture name:" "/tmp" "mydefaultname.png")
```

(ideally in a way compatible with ido) However because the file does not (yet) exist, ido does not prefill the file name, it's like if no file were specified:

[image]

How could I make it work for ido as well?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Drew thanks. So what should I use for questions related to elisp code?

Comment: Use tags that are more specific to what you're asking how to do or what concept you want help with. If it's about *using* Lisp to do something then ask about how to do that something. You'll typically find tags that are relevant for that, including tags related directly to coding, such as `iteration`.

Comment: Ok thanks, for such simple code it's maybe not always relevant, but thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use initial-value instead of default file name:

```lisp
(read-file-name  "Picture name:" "/tmp" nil nil "myedfault.png")
```